# How to check if a table or a column exists in a database?

Tags: java, mysql, database

I am trying to make simple java code that will check if a table and/or a column exists in a MySQL DB. Should I use Java code to do the checking or make a SQL query string and execute that to do the checking ?

EDIT-

@ aleroot -

I tried using your code as shown below. I don't see any tables or columns when I run the code below. I only see this-

```
Driver Loaded.
Got Connection.
```

My DB has got a lot of DB's, tables and columns. I dont know why this program works properly.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

    public class Tester {
  static Connection conn;
  static Statement st;
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try {
  // Step 1: Load the JDBC driver.
  System.out.println("Driver Loaded.");
  // Step 2: Establish the connection to the database.
  String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";

  conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "cowboy", "123456");
  System.out.println("Got Connection.");

  st = conn.createStatement();
} catch (Exception e) {
  System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
  e.printStackTrace();
  System.exit(0);
}

DatabaseMetaData md2 = conn.getMetaData();
ResultSet rsTables = md2.getColumns(null, null, "customers", "name");
 if (rsTables.next()) {
      System.out.println("Exists !");
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Make a query and check if it is successful. If it is, you know table/column exist.

Comment: @FranciscoSpaeth - yes, its jdbc

Answer (score 39, accepted):

To check if a table exist you can use [DatabaseMetaData](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html) in this way :

```
DatabaseMetaData md = connection.getMetaData();
ResultSet rs = md.getTables(null, null, "table_name", null);
if (rs.next()) {
  //Table Exist
}
```

And to check if a column exist you can use it in a similar way :

```
DatabaseMetaData md = connection.getMetaData();
ResultSet rs = md.getColumns(null, null, "table_name", "column_name");
 if (rs.next()) {
      //Column in table exist
    }
```

Comment: If this code does not work for you, try using all caps (Uppercase) for your table_name

Comment: This is neat and leaves the code database-independent.

Comment: @aleroot where do you define connection? When I try `Connection connection = null`, I get a nullpointer exception.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='table_schema'
  AND TABLE_NAME='table_name' 
  AND COLUMN_NAME='column_name'
```

If this sql returns nothing - column not exists. You can execute this query on java side, but this depends what you use (JPA, JDBC, JDBCTemplate).

Answer (score 1):

In Apache Derby (SQL)

E.g. check if column exists:

```
SELECT ss.SCHEMANAME, st.TABLENAME, sc.COLUMNNAME FROM SYS.SYSSCHEMAS ss
INNER JOIN SYS.SYSTABLES st ON st.SCHEMAID = ss.SCHEMAID AND st.TABLENAME = <YOUR TABLE NAME>
INNER JOIN SYS.SYSCOLUMNS sc ON sc.REFERENCEID = st.TABLEID AND sc.COLUMNNAME = <YOUR COLUMN NAME>
WHERE ss.SCHEMANAME = <YOUR SCHEMA>
```

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that you can practically select a column from a table using the following SQL statement (in MySQL):

```
show columns from TABLE_NAME where field = 'FIELD_NAME';
```

You could do something like:

```
...
PreparedStatement preparedStatement =
  connection.prepareStatement(
    "show columns from [TABLE_NAME] where field = ?");
preparedStatement.setString(1, columName);

ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

if (resultSet.next()) {
    System.out.println("column exists!");
} else {
    System.out.println("column doesn't exists!");
}
...
```

Comment: @aleroot this is clear, I didn't worrier about it since the question was regarding MySQL database ;) but even so, thanks I will add a comment to my answer

Comment: Yes, didn't noticed the first time, i added the MySQL tag now . Thanks.

Comment: yes it will, as you can see in the comments already added this is just for mysql (as you commented on the question)