# executeQuery Fails when table does not exist

Tags: java, mysql

I have a system in which there are hundreds of table. So i am getting values from them by making sql query in a loop. But if any table does not exists it quits further execution.
Can i place a condition if any table does not exists then it search for next table....

Comment: If the table is empty, your object should be holding a NULL value. Therefore check for NULL object. If NULL then search for next table.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your quick response....actually i trying

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your quick response....actually i trying such thing..... String query = "SELECT * FROM t1"; rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);   Now t1 is not in my database So it does not execute the next line after stmt.executeQuery(query) and shows the exception "t1 does not exists"...... So where should i place if() Condition

Comment: It should raise an exception in that case, use try catch statement to ignore it if it does not exist. `try { // execute your SQL codes } catch (SQLException e) { }`

Comment: Yes i have applied try{} catch{} and it also catches the exception 
as "table does not exists"..But after this exception..control gets out of the function in which i have placed this code

Comment: Then I believe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699205/how-to-check-if-a-table-or-a-column-exists-in-a-database) method should meet your requirement.

Comment: I got where i was making mistake........i was catching the exception outside my for loop in which i have placed queries....so it was taking control outside my function....Thank you all for your suggessions....

Answer (score 0):

You can use this. This will return list of tables, iterate though it and see if table exist.

```
DatabaseMetaData meta = con.getMetaData();
  ResultSet res = meta.getTables(null, null, null, 
     new String[] {"TABLE"});
  while (res.next()) {
     System.out.println(
        "   "+res.getString("TABLE_CAT") 
       + ", "+res.getString("TABLE_SCHEM")
       + ", "+res.getString("TABLE_NAME")
       + ", "+res.getString("TABLE_TYPE")
       + ", "+res.getString("REMARKS")); 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just catch the exception:

```
List<String> tableNames = ...;
Statement stmt = ...;
ResultSet rs = null;
for (String tableName : tableNames) {
    String sql = buildQuery(tableName);
    try {
        rs = s.executeQuery(sql);
        useData(rs);
    } catch  {
        log.error ("could not execute query on " + tableName);
    } finally {
        if (rs != null) {
            rs.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello , no. of tables are not fixed in my database...i have separate table for each account creation on my site