# try catch block not working with sql

Tags: java, sql, try-catch

I have the following java code:

```
ResultSet rs2 = stmt.executeQuery("select * from teacher");  

        try
        {rs2.getInt("fee");
          System.out.println("found");
          stmt.executeUpdate("alter table teacher drop fee  ");
        }catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println("not found");
            System.err.print(e);
            stmt.executeUpdate("alter table teacher add fee int ");
        }
```

the try never seems to be invoked.

Comment: Are you sure that `executeQuery` is returning without exception? Maybe control flow isn't even getting to the `try`.

Comment: Please post the stacktrace.

Comment: If you're checking if a database column exists, I'd suggest using [DatabaseMetaData](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11699431/899126) instead of querying the contents of a database table

Comment: Not sure if this is the stacktrace:  java.sql.SQLException: After end of result setcom.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Duplicate column name 'fee'

Comment: Also, [`stmt.executeUpdate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate\(java.lang.String\)) is probably not the right call to make when altering a table; I'd use [`stmt.execute`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute\(java.lang.String\)) instead; it's more for a generic use-case

Comment: Does it print `found`? The stacktrace also tell you in which line the error happens. Which line is it exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute `rs2.next()` to get the first (and subsequent) row. As in:

```
ResultSet rs2 = stmt.executeQuery("select * from teacher");  

//rs2.next(); // reads one row!
  rs2.first();


try {
  rs2.getInt("fee");
  System.out.println("found");
  stmt.executeUpdate("alter table teacher drop fee  ");
} catch(SQLException e) {
  System.out.println("not found");
  System.err.print(e);
  stmt.executeUpdate("alter table teacher add fee int ");
}
```

Comment: doesn't work. no change in behavior

Comment: What's the stacktrace?

Comment: Just a note: `rs2.first()` is not implemented on all JDBC drivers. But if it works, then great.